# Load text file into TextArea in JavaFX

Tags: java, text, javafx, textarea

I need to show a text file into TextArea in javaFX.
I'm tired by using this code:

```
@FXML
private void viewHistory(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    HistoryController hc = new HistoryController();
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("EmployeeUpdateHistory.txt"));
        String str;
        File f = new File("EmployeeUpdateHistory.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

        while ((str = in.readLine())!=null) {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/history.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage s1 = new Stage();
            HistoryController historyController = loader.getController();
            historyController.tfHistory.appendText(str);
            Scene s2 = new Scene(root);
            s1.setScene(s2);
            s1.setTitle("History");
            s1.setResizable(false);
            s1.show();
    }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

}
```

but it show just a line in a TextArea and Open many stage(equal with line number).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for creating and showing the stage is inside the while loop. So it will execute for every line in the file. Try moving that code outside of the loop and just have the bit for appending the text inside the loop.

Something like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/history.fxml"));
loader.load();
Parent root = loader.getRoot();
Stage s1 = new Stage();
Scene s2 = new Scene(root);
s1.setScene(s2);
s1.setTitle("History");
s1.setResizable(false);

HistoryController historyController = loader.getController();
while ((str = in.readLine())!=null) {
    historyController.tfHistory.appendText(str);       
}

s1.show();
```